# Why is an autowired controller always null in junit5 tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, junit5

I'm trying to add some unit tests (using **JUnit5**) to my application. But trying to **autowire** a **controller** raises an **assertion error** because the controller is null.

Test class:

```
package com.mydomain.preview.web;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import com.mydomain.preview.web.rest.TestController;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class Test1 {

    @Autowired
    private TestController controller;

    @Test
    public void testContext() throws Exception {
    assertThat(controller).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

Controller class:

```
package com.mydomain.preview.web.rest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping
    public @ResponseBody String greeting() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

pom.xml (irrelevant sections omitted for brevity):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- junit 5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I followed this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

The error I'm getting is: `java.lang.AssertionError: Expecting actual not to be null`. Same error is raised for `mvn test`, `./mvnw test` and running the test from IntelliJ IDEA IDE.

```
SpringBootApplication Class:

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LiquibaseProperties.class, ApplicationProperties.class})
public class MyApp {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApp.class);

    private final Environment env;

    public MyApp(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initApplication() {
        Collection<String> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles());
        if (activeProfiles.contains(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT) && activeProfiles.contains(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)) {
            log.error("You have misconfigured your application! It should not run " +
                "with both the 'dev' and 'prod' profiles at the same time.");
        }
        if (activeProfiles.contains(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT) && activeProfiles.contains(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)) {
            log.error("You have misconfigured your application! It should not " +
                "run with both the 'dev' and 'cloud' profiles at the same time.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main method, used to run the application.
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApp.class);
        DefaultProfileUtil.addDefaultProfile(app);
        Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
        logApplicationStartup(env);
    }

    private static void logApplicationStartup(Environment env) {
        String protocol = "http";
        if (env.getProperty("server.ssl.key-store") != null) {
            protocol = "https";
        }
        String serverPort = env.getProperty("server.port");
        String contextPath = env.getProperty("server.servlet.context-path");
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(contextPath)) {
            contextPath = "/";
        }
        String hostAddress = "localhost";
        try {
            hostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            log.warn("The host name could not be determined, using `localhost` as fallback");
        }
        log.info("\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
                "Application '{}' is running! Access URLs:\n\t" +
                "Local: \t\t{}://localhost:{}{}\n\t" +
                "External: \t{}://{}:{}{}\n\t" +
                "Profile(s): \t{}\n----------------------------------------------------------",
            env.getProperty("spring.application.name"),
            protocol,
            serverPort,
            contextPath,
            protocol,
            hostAddress,
            serverPort,
            contextPath,
            env.getActiveProfiles());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create a example project on github or alike.

Comment: How do you start the application? Can you show the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`?

Comment: @user991710 Added the code to the question.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that @SpringBootTest doesn't find the classes that need to be tested. Try adding `@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestController.class})`

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately it didn't solved the issue.

Comment: After you added it did you do a mvn clean install?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this locally and it works...

Only thing I found that didn't make sense was that `assertThat(controller).isNotNull();` takes two arguments. Try instead `assertNotNull(controller)`

Comment: He is using org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat.

Comment: do you have another `@RequestMapping`?? This was the other thing that failed the test for me.. 2 controllers (or more) with no explicit endpoint caused a clash.

Comment: also do you have spring-boot-starter-web in the dependencies as this is where the `@RequestMapping` dependency comes from